# Updating map when modelsbyref="true"

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, angular-google-maps

I am running into performance problems with many markers on my map [500+, and clustered, but still having problems]

After some research I realise its my apply/disgest cycles that take too long [around 5s in chrome] and the only deep watch I have is baked in the [angular-ui-google-maps](https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/markers).  Switching my markers to `modelsbyref="true"` cuts that in half.

From their docs:

> By default deep watches since modelsbyref is undefined. If set to true, 'true', 'T', and many more then shallow watching is turned on.

So anyway, this gives me a good performance boost [yay].  But now my markers don't udpate [boo].  I thought that replacing an item with a copy would work but perhaps I'm missing something.

My HTML [I removed things like `typeEvent` attributes to keep it small]

```
<ui-gmap-markers models="vm.vehicles"
                 idkey="'Id'"
                 coords="'Plot.coords'"
                 options="'Plot.options'"
                 modelsbyref="true">
</ui-gmap-markers>
```

The code that updates my markers

```
for (let v = 0; v < vehicles.length; v++) {
    const vehicle = vehicles[v];

    // Find the right plot, and update it
    // Note for brevity I've left out the "find new plot" code
    vehicle.Plot = newPlot;

    // Now copy the vehicle to create a new reference - I thought this would update the map
    // It doesnt though ;/
    vehicles[v] = angular.copy(vehicle);
}
```

Comment: Try to `angular.copy` the watchers top level collection (the collectable object `vehicles` in your case), or re-init the whole object with updated markers. Since deep watching is set to `false` it's normal that these deeper elements are not dirty checked.

Comment: Whats the quickest way to reinit the object with the updated markers?

Comment: Copy the current object, update the markers, set the updated object to the `$scope` variable.

Comment: I tried `this.vehicles = this.vehicles.slice()` but it didnt work. It should though shouldnt it?